# SVG widthout using IDs

Tags: javascript, html, svg

for example we have defs and rect separately, so we must use ID

```
<defs>
    <linearGradient id="MyGradient">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#000" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#fff" />
    </linearGradient>
</defs>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="256" height="32" fill="url(#MyGradient)"/>
```

How can I do the same but without using ID (MyGradient). Maybe with JavaScript?

something like this

```
<rect x="0" y="0" width="256" height="32">
    <linearGradient>
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#000" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#fff" />
    </linearGradient>
</rect>
```

doesn't work :(

Comment: This would (roughly) be possible in XAML, but not in SVG.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t believe you can apply a gradient in SVG without defining the gradient and linking to it with an ID. What reason do you not want to use an ID?

You may be able to apply a CSS gradient in the future, but I don't think this works yet, and at any rate isn’t as cross platform as using the regular SVG gradient.

Comment: I don't want my IDs to interfere with others IDs as I don't know where my code will be working.
I want something
var grad=/*create gradient (in difs)*/;
var rect=/*crete rect*/;
rect.fill.gradient=grad;

Comment: You could always prefix the IDs with something unique that is unlikely to clash, such as "GRAD" or something.

Comment: Yes, of course, it's easy to guess using IDs like name+id+random, but I find it strange to use IDs if they are not needed. Not needed because they're created by JavaScript.